# issues with NHiberntate Persistence API "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named ""

Tags: nhibernate, appharbor

I use NHibernate's implementation of JPA (NPA) and I embedded the `persistence.xml` config file, but my application on AppHarbor shows:

> "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named persistenceUnit"

It works fine on my local machine.

Comment: @Beetee Please do not use code formatting for words which aren't code. [Have a look at this for more information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/4244993) *(I will remove that comment when you acknowledged it, so remove yours as well if you add a comment)*

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the relevant files are included in your build output? Try downloading build output from AppHarbor and check that everything is where it's supposed to be. (If not, you likely need to set "Build Action" to "Content" for the file in question.